# Faster (vectorized) way to do this pandas formula with dates

Tags: python, pandas

I'm building a time series, trying to get a more efficient way to do this - ideally vectorized.
The pandas apply with list comprehension step is very slow (on a big data set).

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Dummy data:
todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
xdates = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=4, freq='D')
categories = list(2*'A') + list(2*'B')
d = {'xdate': xdates, 'periods': [8]*2 + [2]*2, 'interval': [3]*2 + [12]*2}
df = pd.DataFrame(d,index=categories)

# This step is slow:
df['sdates'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x.xdate + pd.DateOffset(months=k*x.interval) for k in range(x.periods)], axis=1)
# This step is quite quick, but shown here for completeness
df = df.explode('sdates')
```

Maybe something like this:

```py
df['sdates'] = [df.xdate + df.periods * [df.interval.astype('timedelta64[M]')]]
```

but the syntax isn't quite right.
This code

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(d,index=categories)
df['m_offsets'] = df.interval.apply(lambda x: list(range(0, 72, x)))
df = df.explode('m_offsets')
df['sdate'] = df.xdate + df.m_offsets * pd.DateOffset(months=1)
```

I think is similar to one of the answers, but the last step, pd.DateOffset gives a warning:

> PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting array of DateOffsets to DatetimeArray not vectorized

I tried building something along the lines of one answer, but as mentioned the modular arithmatic needs tweaking a lot to deal with edge cases, and haven't figured that out yet (calendar monthrange wasn't playing nicely).
This function doesn't run:

```
from calendar import monthrange
def add_months(df, date_col, n_col):
    """ Adds ncol months do date_col """
    z = df.copy()
    # calculate new year/month/day and convert to datetime
    z['year'] = (z[date_col].dt.year * 12 + (z[date_col].dt.month-1) + z[n_col]) // 12
    z['month'] = ((z[date_col].dt.month + z[n_col] - 1) % 12) + 1
    x,x = monthrange(z.year, z.month)
    z['days_in_month'] = monthrange(z.year, z.month)
    z['target_day'] = z[date_col].dt.day
    # z['day'] = min(z.target_day, z.days_in_month)
    z['day'] = z.days_in_month
    z['sdates'] = pd.to_datetime(z[['year', 'month', 'day']])
    return z['sdates']
```

This works, for now, but the dateoffset is a really heavy step.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(d,index=categories)
df['m_offsets'] = df.interval.apply(lambda x: list(range(0, 72, x)))
df = df.explode('m_offsets')
df['sdates'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.xdate + pd.DateOffset(months=x.m_offsets), axis=1)
```

Comment: in your real data, do you have a limited amount of different periods and intervals ? like in your example you have 2 couples (period-interval)

Comment: Have you looked into using numpy's np.vectorize() ?

Comment: @Ben.T there are a limited number of periods/intervals.
- Intervals are basically 1,3,6,12.
- Periods could be andthing from 5 to 60
i.e. 5 years (1*60 or 5*12)

Comment: and how big is your big dataset?

Comment: @Ben.T around 170k rows

Comment: the main issue is that adding `DateOffsets` to a series of dates is not vectorized. Simple calculations (such as adding calculated quantities to date parts: `m = (m - 1 + months) % 12 + 1`, etc.) won't work because it would sometimes result in non-existing dates (e.g. `'2021-02-31'`).

Comment: @PierreD Actually it seems relatively easy. What needs to be done is clipping of the days exceeding the number of days in month. I've updated my answer (it's still 20x+ faster than the original and the version that you posted)

Comment: it still won't work for leap years, and if the dates are tz-aware, then you'll get even more headaches with daylight savings...  If you are going to try (some people have done crazier things), then make sure you have a comprehensive test suite with diverse data and against the "ground truth" of using `DateOffset()`.

Comment: @PierreD Why would it not work for leap years? And how would daylight savings affect this calculation? Can you give an example?

Comment: @perl: with your clever use of `.dt.days_in_month`, it's all good and you pulled off a correct calculation (congrats)!  Any reason why you deleted your answer? It is a good one and the fastest in this specific case of `DateOffset()` of an integer (but variable) number of months.

Comment: Sure, it's just that @pybynumbers reposted more or less the same thing as an answer, and I don't think we should keep multiple answers that are extremely similar here on SO (less text to read for anyone facing a similar problem in the future)

Comment: urgh - I deleted my post before reading this - and mine didn't include everything from your update...
@perl your input was super helpful. Thank you.
I'm going to accept PierreD's answer as speed is comparable and I suspect is little more accurate (does dateoffset correctly infer that it is start or end of month, - think 1 month after 28th Feb, end of month would be 31 March... Not sure which works best here)

Comment: @pybynumbers OK, so who should undelete, you or me? :)

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The OP should not have posted an answer that is a near duplicate of yours (no biggie: it can be fixed). You should undelete yours. It is a good one and deserves credit.

Comment: no i didn't downvote, and deleted my own answer. sorry, and thanks again for the help. realyl awesome stuff

Comment: @perl: yes, I initially downvoted when the answer was erroneous, but then upvoted when you fixed it. As I said, it is a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Semi-vectorized way**

As I say below, I don't think there is a pure vectorized way to add a variable and general `DateOffset` to a `Series` of `Timestamp`s.  @perl solution works in the case where the `DateOffset` is an exact multiple of 1 month.

Now, adding a single constant `DateOffset` *is* vectorized, so we can use the following. It capitalizes on the fact that there is a limited set of distinct values for the date offset. It is also relatively fast, and it is correct for any `DateOffset` and dates:

```py
n = df['periods'].values
period_no = np.repeat(n - n.cumsum(), n) + np.arange(n.sum())
z = pd.DataFrame(
    np.repeat(df.reset_index().values, repeats=n, axis=0),
    columns=df.reset_index().columns,
).set_index('index')
z = z.assign(madd=period_no * z['interval'])

z['sdates'] = z['xdate']

for madd in set(z['madd'].unique()):
    z.loc[z['madd'] == madd, 'sdates'] += pd.DateOffset(months=madd)
```

Timing:

```py
# modified large dummy data:
N = 170_000
todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
xdates = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=N, freq='H')
categories = np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'), N)
d = {'xdate': xdates, 'periods': np.random.randint(1,10,N), 'interval': np.random.randint(1,12,N)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d,index=categories)

%%time (the above)
CPU times: user 3.49 s, sys: 13.5 ms, total: 3.51 s
Wall time: 3.51 s
```

(Note: for 10K rows using the generation above, I see times of ~240ms, but of course it is dependent on how many distinct month offsets you have in your data).

Example result (for one draw of 170K rows as per above):

```py
>>> z.tail()
                    xdate periods interval madd              sdates
index                                                              
B     2040-08-25 06:00:00       8        8   48 2044-08-25 06:00:00
B     2040-08-25 06:00:00       8        8   56 2045-04-25 06:00:00
D     2040-08-25 07:00:00       3        2    0 2040-08-25 07:00:00
D     2040-08-25 07:00:00       3        2    2 2040-10-25 07:00:00
D     2040-08-25 07:00:00       3        2    4 2040-12-25 07:00:00
```

**Correction on the initial answer**

I stand corrected: my original answer is not vectorized either. The first part, exploding the DataFrame and building the number of months to add, is vectorized and very fast. But the second part, adding a `DateOffset` of a variable number of months, is not.

I hope I am wrong, but I don't think there is currently a way to do that second part in a vectorized way.

Direct date-parts manipulation (e.g. `month = (month - 1 + n_months) % 12 + 1`, etc.) are bound to fail for corner cases (e.g. `'2021-02-31'`).  Short of replicating the logic used in `DateOffset`, this is not going to work for certain cases.

**Initial answer**

Here is a vectorized way:

```py
n = df.periods.values
period_no = np.repeat(n - n.cumsum(), n) + np.arange(n.sum())
z = pd.DataFrame(
    np.repeat(df.reset_index().values, repeats=n, axis=0),
    columns=df.reset_index().columns,
).set_index('index').assign(period_no=period_no)

z['sdates'] = z['period_no']  * z['interval'] * pd.DateOffset(months=1) + z['xdate']
```

Comment: Interesting, does it not give you "PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to DatetimeArray not vectorized"?

Comment: Actually, timed your response and it doesn't show any improvement over the original (see my answer). Downvoting, but happy to reverse if I missed something

Comment: ah, yes indeed, I was in a notebook that had suppressed the warning. But I don't buy that you can do a correct `date + DateOffset(months=1)` with simple modulo-12 arithmetic.

Comment: This is super fast for me. 10 minutes into 10 seconds. means I don't have time to make a cup of tea while the script runs

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option. You're adding months, so we can actually calculate new year/month/day by only dealing with integers in a vectorized way, and then create datetime from these y/m/d combinations:

```
def f_proposed(df):
    z = df.copy()
    z = z.reset_index()

    # repeat xdate as many times as the number of periods
    z = z.loc[np.repeat(z.index, z['periods'])]
    
    # calculate k number of months to add
    z['k'] = z.groupby(level=0).cumcount() * z['interval']
    
    # calculate new year/month/day and convert to datetime
    z['year'] = (z['xdate'].dt.year * 12 + z['xdate'].dt.month - 1 + z['k']) // 12
    z['month'] = (z['xdate'].dt.month - 1 + z['k']) % 12 + 1
    
    # clip day to days_in_month
    z['days_in_month'] = pd.to_datetime(
        z['year'].astype(str)+'-'+z['month'].astype(str)+'-01').dt.days_in_month
    z['day'] = np.clip(z['xdate'].dt.day, 0, z['days_in_month'])
    
    z['sdates'] = pd.to_datetime(z[['year', 'month', 'day']])
    
    # drop temporary columns
    z = z.set_index('index').drop(columns=['k', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'days_in_month'])
    return z
```

To compare performance with the original, I've generated a test dataset with 10,000 rows.

Here's my timings (~23x speedup for 10K):

```
%timeit f_proposed(z)
82.7 ms ± 222 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit f_original(z)
1.92 s ± 2.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

P.S. For 170K it takes about 1.39s with `f_proposed` and 33.6 s with `f_original` on my machine

Comment: it's fast but wrong. For example, you'll get errors like `"ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: time data '20230004' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)"`.

Comment: there is no such month as '0', so the simple modulo-12 calculation doesn't work. Further, trying to simply add a number of months to a date sometimes doesn't work: what would '2021-01-31' + 1 month give?

Comment: @PierreD spot on - i tried using this answer but quickly hit problems

Comment: @PierreD: yes, good points re both '0' month and days exceeding the days_in_month. I've fixed both, now it works correctly and is still 20x+ faster

Comment: @pybynumbers Can you try again with the updated version above?

Comment: How do you deal with leap years?... And daytime savings...  Believe me, that's a rabbit hole...

Comment: @PierreD What about the leap years/daytime savings? It doesn't affect this logic, or does it? Can you find a case when it breaks?

Comment: @perl I think this is good enough for me. I can't think of how it could break. clipping the date is fine, since you only do it once, not building the next iteration from a clipped date.

Comment: oh, I see: good use of `.dt.days_in_month`, very clever. The issues with daylight savings occur in the more general case where you deal with arbitrary date offsets (including intraday resolution). BTW, I would still add time-of-day to your solution, it probably won't affect timing but will be just a touch more generic.

Comment: Also, just to be clear: the solution I propose is generic (any DateOffset) and takes 240ms for 10K rows in my tests, and 3.5s for 170K rows. It isn't 20x slower.

Comment: Yes, the latest one with looping over the number of months to add. I think it's a good one if you have a small number of different offsets (which is probably the case here)

Comment: Anyway, despite the heated discussion (or maybe because of it?), OP now has not one but 2 pretty good options to cut the execution time by 10-20x, which is not a bad outcome :)